# Javascript fill input with value containing multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have an input element in my form. When i press submit button i call a function which writes into it a c++ program from [Ace Editor Api](https://ace.c9.io/)

My Ace editor getValue() functions returns me the code which i write into the input element by

```
document.getElementById("id_code").value = editor.getValue();
//alert(editor.getValue());
//alert(document.getElementById("id_code").value);
//id_code is id of my input element in html
//this snippet is called from function onclick submit button
```

But ace editor contains new lines which are escaped by this snippet. Like i alerted the two things (mentioned as comments) in browser and here are the screenshots
[image: Ace editor one]

and

[image: input element one]

As you can see these two differ by newlines and i dont want this. How to resolve this?

Comment: which is the function you say is replacing the line breaks?

Comment: sorry i meant this snippet, edited!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input element in html contains only 1 line. So to store multiple line text, use textarea!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a function on the client side like the one below

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function repCRLFData(value)
    {
        var newValue = null;
        var cr = "\\r";
        var lf = "\\n";

        try
        {
            newValue = value.split(cr).join("");
            newValue = newValue.split(lf).join("");
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert("repCRLFData Error:  " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

        }

        return newValue;
    }

</script>
```

and call it using

document.getElementById("id_code").value = repCRLFData(editor.getValue());

Comment: Perhaps, I'm not clear as to the problem.  I thought that you wanted to remove carriage returns and/or line feeds.  If so, have you tried unescaping the  data from editor.getValue()?  e.g. - document.getElementById("id_code").value = repCRLFData(unescape(editor.getValue()));

Comment: yeah i found my mistake, i wanted to store mutiple lines in input form but i found it isnt possible! Anyways thanks, i sorta got hint from your answer :) Cheers!